# Shift parts of multiple lines to new lines in vim simultaneously

Tags: vim, newline, textblock, shift

I have a block of code, e.g.

```
    ...
    elseif a:flag ==# "replace" return "fg"
    elseif a:flag ==# "visual"  return "#b58900"
    elseif a:flag ==# "insert"  return "#268bd2"
    elseif a:flag ==# "normal"  return "#859900"
    elseif a:flag ==# "replace" return "#dc322f"
    elseif a:flag ==# "visual"  return 3
    elseif a:flag ==# "insert"  return 4
    elseif a:flag ==# "normal"  return 2
    elseif a:flag ==# "replace" return 1
    ...
```

Now I want to move the `return`part below the `ìf` statements of all lines at once. Is this possible in vim?
I tried `<C-v>I<CR><ESC>`. But that does only move the first `return`to a new line.

Comment: the last 5 lines will never be called/returned. :D  I hope you just paste lines together to make this example.

Comment: Indeed it was just a quick example. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In command mode:

```
:%s/return/\r\t\treturn/gc
```

Omit the trailing gc to avoid the confirmation.

Comment: the 2nd return could be written in `&`

Comment: With your cursor starting on 'return', this simplifies down to:  `*:%s//\r&`

Comment: Golf: `:%s/return/\r\t\t&/gc`. May want to also mention using a visual range: `:'<,'>s/return/\r\t\t&/gc`

Comment: Ok, so there's no way without using a regex search & replace?

Comment: Search/replace is the fastest way.

Comment: @Ube if you want to play with macro, it works too. but different goal. "get the work done fast" vs "learn/practice/play vim"

Comment: @Ube didn't we answer your original question?

Comment: Well, yes. Accepted but not exactly what I was looking for (a "simple" key combination). I guess I didn't formulate my question clear enough.